# How to change the date format in the model history section in the Django admin panel from Gregorian to Jalali?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I changed the date and time of the admin panel using the Jalali-date package, and now if I go to the special page for each model in the admin panel
It shows the date of manufacture in Jalali format.
But if I go to the history section of that model, I see that the dates are displayed normally in the Django system.

Note: Jalali Library transforms the world standard history into the conventional history in Islamic countries

the package i have used:
[django-jalali-date](https://pypi.org/project/django-jalali-date/)

my models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django_jalali.db import models as jmodels
class Thought(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name = 'عنوان تسک')
    content = models.CharField(max_length=400, verbose_name = 'متن')
    date_posted = jmodels.jDateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='تاریخ')

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, max_length=10, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, verbose_name = 'کاربر')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'تسک'
        verbose_name_plural = 'تسک ها'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    

class Profile(models.Model):

    profile_pic = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, default='Default.png', verbose_name = 'عکس پروفایل')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, max_length=10, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name = 'کاربر')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'پروفایل'
        verbose_name_plural = 'پروفایل ها'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

my admin file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Thought, Profile
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from jalali_date import datetime2jalali
from jalali_date.admin import ModelAdminJalaliMixin

# Core
@admin.register(Thought)
class ThoughtAdmin(ModelAdminJalaliMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title', 'content', 'date_posted']
    def get_created_jalali(self, obj):
        return datetime2jalali(obj.created).strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')

admin.site.unregister(User)
@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(ModelAdminJalaliMixin, UserAdmin):
    list_display = ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_superuser', 'date_joined', 'last_login']
    def get_created_jalali(self, obj):
        return datetime2jalali(obj.created).strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')

admin.site.register(Profile)
```

my config for jalali_date package in settings file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'admin_persian',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'journal.apps.JournalConfig',
    'crispy_forms',
    'crispy_bootstrap5',
    'jalali_date',
]



# Jalali Setting

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fa'

import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "Persian_Iran.UTF-8")

JALALI_DATE_DEFAULTS = {
   # if change it to true then all dates of the list_display will convert to the Jalali.
   'LIST_DISPLAY_AUTO_CONVERT': True,
   'Strftime': {
        'date': '%y/%m/%d',
        'datetime': '%H:%M:%S _ %y/%m/%d',
    },
    'Static': {
        'js': [
            # loading datepicker
            'admin/js/django_jalali.min.js',
            # OR
            # 'admin/jquery.ui.datepicker.jalali/scripts/jquery.ui.core.js',
            # 'admin/jquery.ui.datepicker.jalali/scripts/calendar.js',
            # 'admin/jquery.ui.datepicker.jalali/scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker-cc.js',
            # 'admin/jquery.ui.datepicker.jalali/scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker-cc-fa.js',
            # 'admin/js/main.js',
        ],
        'css': {
            'all': [
                'admin/jquery.ui.datepicker.jalali/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css',
            ]
        }
    },
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/i18n/

# LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fa'


TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Tehran'

USE_I18N = True
# New
USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

The display of date in the history section of Django admin panel is as below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcmdQ.jpg)

but i want to the The display of date in the history section of Django admin panel be:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8U4q.jpg)